# I seek a word for the expectation that any arbitrary group of people can be held morally accountable as though they're a single moral agent

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I think this must be a cognitive error of some kind. I just now read the phrase, "the hypocrisy of the left", and it occurred to me that hypocrisy is a moral action, which can be taken only by a moral agent, ie, a person. And "the left" (or "the left wing" or "the political right") are not persons; they don't have stable personalities, they're not moral agents, they can't engage in hypocrisy.

Is there a word for this kind of error, calling on a (usually ill-defined) group of people to exhibit a stable personality and moral accountability?

Single-word request requirements:

- Sample sentence: "You get an F for your paper entitled 'The Sins of The Right', because it's based entirely on a cognitive error known as *homunculus-ex-vulgus*."
- Not being sure where to start with a dictionary or thesaurus, I've tried googling *misattribution of moral agency* and *cognitive error moral agency*, also *group single personality*; I went through [50 Common Cognitive Distortions](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/in-practice/201301/50-common-cognitive-distortions) on Psychology Today. I haven't found anything that even sounds similar.
- My criteria for choosing the best word: If it's a clinical or technical word, then I guess the best word would be one that literally means what I'm talking about. If metaphor is the only thing available, I guess the best word would be the most neutral-sounding, the least baggage, the kind of word that wouldn't put people on the defensive.
- Words I've considered: honestly, *homunculus-ex-vulgus fallacy* is the **only** thing I've come up with.
- A compound word or phrase is fine. Cheers

P.S. I would be most grateful for any feedback concerning the downvotes.

Comment: The *hypocrisy of the left*, as far as I immediately took it to mean, refers to the *political* left. In other words, liberalism. (In the US, it would be represented by members of the Democratic party). Think [*left-wing politics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-wing_politics). I'm curious how you got the notion that "the left" is talking about something else. Or that "the left" would have anything necessarily to do with a stable personality or morality (any more or less than "the right"). What is the source of your quote?

Comment: I don't think that's a cognitive error, so I doubt you'll find a term for it.

Comment: @JasonBassford I took "the left" to mean "the political left", just as you have said. It makes no sense to speak of the hypocrisy of the political left. Hypocrisy is a moral action, that can be taken only by a moral agent, ie, a person. The political left is not a person. I don't know which quote you're referring to. I didn't quote anything. Peace

Comment: @Minty Any guess as to what kind of error (phenomenon?) it is?

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? The political right accuse the political left of hypocrisy all the time. (Just as the political left accuse the political right in reverse.) Accusing another political party of hypocrisy (or a particular rival candidate) is very common. As for my mention of  a quote, you say in your question, "I just now read the phrase." I wanted to know *where* you read it.

Comment: @JasonBassford Ah, I see, you've mistaken me. I'm not making political conversation. Perhaps that's why someone downvoted me. Please notice in my example sentence, "The Sins of The Right" being an example of the same phenomenon. It makes no sense to speak of the "sins of the right".

Comment: @JasonBassford Forgive me, I was the one who misunderstood. I'll start over. To ascribe moral agency to a group of people, especially one so nebulous as "the political left", can be taken only as a very loose metaphor. One can hardly expect "the political left" to behave as a single entity with moral responsibilities.

Comment: @JasonBassford I guess you could find the "hypocrisy of the left" just about anywhere, but since you asked, I read it [here](https://radio.foxnews.com/2016/02/22/ep-1-ben-shapiro-when-diversity-becomes-a-problem/) Peace

Comment: You could call it personification of the group, I suppose... but I don't think the kind of unity you see as being presupposed by words like *intend* is to be found at the level of the individual either. IMHO intention is always an abstraction and you are seeing a difference of kind when there is only a difference of degree.

Comment: That group is a moral agent. That's what political parties are. That's why they are formed in the first place and how they define themselves (and denigrate each other). They have stated positions on moral issues such as human rights issues and social security payments and medical treatment access. What they aren't is an arbitrary group of people. They are people who have sought to become members *because* of the moral issues.

Comment: @PhilSweet Point taken, thanks. I'll remove "Democrats" from my question. I'm trying to refer to actual arbitrary groups; it was only carelessness that led me to say "Democrats". Let's say "the left" or "the right" -- that's the kind of arbitrary group I mean.

Comment: It's a particular type of **stereotyping**. 'The left' is a **metonym** meaning  'those people having left-wing inclinations / views ...' with 'left' in the political sense being a well known metaphor. Stereotyping involves **hyperbole** ('the left' implying 'all those people who can in any way be considered to be associated with any left-wing views ...').  // The whole exemplifies the **Fallacy of Composition** (faulty induction) which infers that something is true of the whole from the fact that it is manifestly true from some part of the whole. But that truth doesn't need to be unsavoury.

Comment: Suppose someone said "The immorality of Nazism".  Would you have the same problem that you appear to have with "the hyprocrisy of the left" and similar phrases?  I can't help you with the English, or the philosophy, but the phrase means the same as "The immorality of Nazis" or "The immorality of supporters of Naziism."  Thus the answer of Mari-Lou A seems to me to fit your question.

Comment: @ab2 Interesting point. Here's the crux of the issue, I think. The claim of hypocrisy in particular amounts to a complaint that "the left" is not a monolithic entity with a distinct personality, eg, the disappointment that some people on "the left" were ok/indifferent to President Clinton's sexual escapades, while others on "the left" make a big deal out of President Trump's comments about sexually assaulting women. It's the expectation that this ill-defined group, "the left" (or "the right"), be morally accountable, with a stable personality as though it were a person.

Comment: @ab2 I was going to address each one of your points about Nazism, but figured it would be better to try to illuminate the central issue. I could tell you how those are different from "hypocrisy of the left", but only if you think it would be useful or interesting. Cheers

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's promising, I'll look into it. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for the term **metonymy**, a word or phrase that represents a thing, or concept. The expression ‘the left‘ simply stands for [members/supporters of] ***the left*** wing [political party].

Other examples of metonymy,

> **Crown** - in place of a royal person
>   *We will swear loyalty to the crown.*

> **The White House** or *The Oval Office* - used in place of the President or White House staff
>   *The White House will be making an announcement around noon today.*

> **Heart** - to refer to love or emotion
>   *My dear, you have all of my heart.*

> **Dish** - for an entire plate of food
>   That fancy fish dish you made was the best of the evening.

Source: [Your Dictionary](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-metonymy.html)   See also *[Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/synecdoche-metonymy-usage-differences)* explanation.

Whether or not you agree that members or supporters of the left are hypocrites that is a separate *political* issue.

Comment: Oh my, I worded my question so badly. I have misled you and another commenter in the same wrong direction. I've edited my original question. I realize that when I said "this concept makes no sense," I didn't stop to mention exactly which concept I was talking about. I would welcome your thoughts on the revised question. Cheers

Comment: The answer is "prejudice" @GreatBigBore The question is much clearer now, thanks. I might leave this answer up as a warning to other users :)

Comment: +1 *The choir sang* is understood to mean that the *members* of the choir sang. Or *the board of directors didn't like your presentation* is understood to mean that members of the board, collectively, didn't like your presentation.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm really blowing this whole thing. I'm talking about, for example, placing moral accountability on "the political left", which is what it means to say "the hypocrisy of the political left". I'm talking about treating this arbitrary, nebulous group of abstract people as though the group itself is a moral agent. Am I making any sense?

Comment: @GreatBigBore Don't apologize. I read the question in too much of a rush and answered it accordingly. It's leaning towards philosophy I fear, try to keep it focused on the English language.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Heh, now that you mention it, it does seem more like a philosophy discussion than a request for a word. Hmm, I'd delete the question, but I think the system won't let that happen after it's been up this long. I'll go back to the drawing board and probably post something on the philosophy SE site. If you have any thoughts on what might be best to do here, I'm listening. Peace

Comment: If I delete the answer, you can then delete the question. Or you could just leave it up and see what happens.

Comment: @SaganRitual Mari-LouA has answered the question appropriately as posed by you. If you say **the Left** cannot be a moral agent, that's right. Because "the Left" on its face cannot be a single moral agent. However, If **the Left** is taken to mean all people in the **Left**, she's right. The Left is metonymic to "all Leftists" which are people. This is not philosophy; it is a poetic device, as it were.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. I offer some challenges to your assertion: first, even "all Leftists" is an arbitrary group, given that "Leftist" has as many meanings as there are people. Second, even if there were some non-arbitrary way of delineating the group, it would be a cognitive error to call on the group to behave as a distinct personality, as though it were a single person--with moral agency, no less. Please note that Mari-LouA had the misfortune of answering an early version of my question, very badly worded and confusing. I've made many corrections since then. Peace

Comment: @SaganRitual I think your use of the phrase "a cognitive error" to describe what some pundit called "the hypocrisy of the left" is a misnomer, and I also think you are mixing up language, logic and philosophy. :)

Comment: @Lambie Mari-LouA also mentioned that it's in danger of becoming a philosophy question rather than language. But I went and posted a (much better) version of my question on a philosophy forum, and was much disappointed. I've gained far more from the conversation here on ESE. Are you suggesting that I'm giving too much credit to the pundit? Expecting him to be more thoughtful than is reasonable for the average faceless loudmouth?

Comment: @SaganRitual No, I am saying that this question is about poetics and meaning (semantics). It is neither philosophy nor logic. The pundit has nothing to do with this. This type of metonymy is everywhere. the Left, the Right, the silent majority, and so forth. The Good, The Bad and The Ugly [that's a joke].